# References for Italian-American slang (cross-post from English Language & Usage)

Tags: resource-request, american-english, slang

This morning I have asked the following question on the English Language & Usage SE:

As an Italian, I find the interaction between my language and the English language fascinating. One big problem I am facing now is the scarceness of academic resources on the subject. Apart from some websites and blog or newspaper articles, there isn't much one can read about the Italian language in an AE linguistic context.

My greatest interest lies in the sociolinguistic dynamics of said interaction, but anything that has to do with the subject will be greatly appreciated.

In fear of it being closed (after I got told off by a member of said SE), I decided to post it here, where it might be welcomed due to its having to do both with linguistic research and academic resources.

Link to the original question:

> [References for Italian-American slang](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/400939/204250)